# MySQL - Get column names from table and display them (using PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to take the column names from a table and display them, so i can compare them later.
To get the names, i tried:

```
$entry = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM  table');
```

and

```
$entry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'");
```

I don't know whether this runs correctly or not, since i don't get an error message there.
If i try to print the contents of $entry via echo, i keep getting errors.
Previously in my code, i print other entries using:

```
$test = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT DISTINCT LK_Release FROM table');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($test))
{
echo "Releasename: " . "$row->LK_Release". "<br>";
... }
```

This output works for me.
What i tried to output the columnnames:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($entry))
{
echo $row;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yes that is correct `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table`, just fetch it like a normal query

Comment: Could you post the code that didn't work, instead of the code that did?

Comment: Sure. What i tried last was: while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($entry))
   {
 echo $row;
 }

Comment: var_dump($row); What does it show?

Comment: var_dump($row); shows information about all my columns in the table.

Comment: You cannot echo an object array. Instead try to convert as numeric array or **foreach ($objarray as $key => $value) { $object->$key = $value; }** inside while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is already correct. But you lack something in the fetching:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($entry))
{
    echo $row->Field . '<br/>';
              // ^ access the objects properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statements are nearly equivalent:

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

You can use DESCRIBE:

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Or in newer versions you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND    TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Or you can use SHOW COLUMNS:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;
```